# Building with dokan.lib

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have downloaded the `Dokan Library 0.6.0` (used to write a file system in user mode).
I'm using VS 2013 and have created a project to build the sample called mirror.c. It uses a LIB called `dokan.lib`. It compiles just fine but the linker gives an error saying
 `"unresolved external symbol __imp__DokanMain@8"`. I dumped the `lib` and `__imp__DokanMain@8` does exist within `dokan.lib`.

Under Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories, I added `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Dokan\DokanLibrary"` but that didn't help. Then I changed that to `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Dokan\DokanLibrary\dokan.lib"` but that also didn't help.

I have read everything at the dokan web site but nothing talks about building with Visual Studio.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm using VS2013 Ultimate and WDK 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move "dokan.lib" from Settings -> Linker ->General -> Additional Library Directories. This is meant to include only the paths to the libraries. You can leave the path to the library in tact in there (i.e, C:\Program Files (x86)\Dokan\DokanLibrary).

Place the "dokan.lib" in Settings->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. I had misunderstood the meaning of some of the settings.

Comment: Thanks! I had the exact same problem.